# Can you mix .NET Framework 4.* in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, project, versioning, solution, .net-framework-version

Let's say a Visual Studio Solution has 40 + projects within it; are you able to mix (for example) .NET 4.6.1 framework projects with 4.7.2 framework projects?

Will it cause problems?

Note: this question is specific to .NET Framework 4

Comment: higher version could consume lower version projects, but VS gives you warning. best is to have all projects in same .net version

Comment: @magicandre1981 I was actually getting a `namespace not found` error when trying to mix `4.6.1` with `4.7.2`

Comment: I tried it some years ago with 4 and 4.5. Maybe it is blocked now. why can't you configure them to use all the same version?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I could, but since I work on such a huge codebase, it would be a lot of work to just update every project that way. Some of them also use .NET Core

Comment: I have no other idea except of changing it to same .net version. do it outside of VS via editor/script to modify csproj/app.config, this is faster, VS is slow in this case.